Stop loading all the visualisations/queries when a Dashboard is opened
We have some large dashboards, which contains multiple queries that will take time to load. When a dashboard is opened, the DB CPU is increasing to 90% and ultimately Redash is going down.
I want to stop loading all these queries at once. The user can refresh each query if he wants to. However, because there are many queries and all are loading at once, Redash is crashing down and we are getting 504 Gateway Timeout.
We are using Redash V8.
Redash should not load all the queries in a dashboard at once.
